# SVG.js How do I add an svg to the HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, svg.js

I have a page that will show several svg images that will be generated from json data. I created a javascript class that will generate the svg but I don't know how to add it to the dom.

As a simple example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="myrow">
            *i want to add the image here*
        </div>
    </body>
</html
```

I tried something like:

```
let x = new mysvgobject(json);
x.img.addTo('.myrow');
```

but it doesn't work. I think I need to convert that x.img to something the HTML will understand but don't know what that might be. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `mysvgobject`? You tagged this [tag:svg.js] but I can't find `mysvgobject` mentioned in the documentation for the library. You should read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. (What is `json` for that matter?)

Comment: [doesn't work](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) isn't a useful description of a problem. What happens? What errors are reported?

Comment: adding size?  `x.img.addTo('.myrow').size(300, 300)` «SVG.js does not set a size for the document automatically. So make sure to call size() with appropriate values.» https://svgjs.dev/docs/3.0/getting-started/

Comment: or maybe `x.addTo('.myrow').size(300, 300)`, I'm not sure what's `img` there

Comment: Quentin - mysvgobject is the javascript class that creates the image. It has a constructor that takes json data and creates the image. It has a getter on it that I named 'img' that returns the svg item. "doesn't work" means nothing happens. No errors are displayed. json is javascript object notation. Its just a way of passing data around.

Comment: Event getting this simple jsfiddle working would be a help: https://jsfiddle.net/dlinds54/ket4mcyz/

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer. Just had to drill down further into the svg produced by the class with:

```
x.img.node.outerHTML
```

and drop it on the page.